# What is alternative for GROUP_CONCAT() using Apache Drill?

Tags: mysql, json, apache-drill

I am trying to use Apache Drill. GROUP_CONCAT() is not supporting. I need to group concat the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Drill does not have alternatives to group_concat but you can try to develop your [custom aggregate function](https://drill.apache.org/docs/developing-an-aggregate-function/).

Comment: Thanks Arina Yelchiyeva.